# Horsepower at certain RPM point without knowing torque?

Tags: classical-mechanics, frequency, power

I want to know the horsepower produced by an engine at certain RPM by knowing another certain RPM point?

Let's suppose that an engine produces 200 hp at 4000 RPM, how many horsepower is produced by that engine at 5000 RPM?

What is the process?, Do I miss another factors?

Comment: For real engines I think the correct answer is *"You measure a sufficiently dense selection of points and interpolate"*; that is, you can't do it *ab initio*.

Answer (score 1):

You have to assume a certain shape for the torque curve. For example if the torque is more of less constant then

$$ T = \frac{P_1}{\omega_1} = \frac{P_2}{\omega_2} $$

$$ \frac{200}{4000} = \frac{P}{5000} $$

It helps to know the rpm of peak torque, as typically torque varies as a parabola near that point. Depending on the valvetrain, the torque curve will have one or two humps, and it it has a turbo then all bets are off as torque values a dynamically manipulated by the ECU.